# How to delete in MongoDB records whose hour is not a multiple of 12

Tags: java, mongodb, scala, casbah

I am using MongoDB through the Casbah driver and I am storing documents which contain a date field, which is in my java world a Java DateTime. I would need to perform similar queries:

- Remove all records with day any but hour falling into a certain interval
- Remove all records with day any but hour not a multiple of 3.
- Find all records with day any and hour 11

Is there a simple way to do it , given that the conversion helpers for Joda DateTime store a single field? Should I probably refactor it to have a Time Field and a Date Field?

Answer (score 1):

The range operators on date times will only work on a single distinct range from year-month-day-hour-etc downwards,  so wouldn't work for your queries where you're effectively asking for many distinct ranges.

MongoDB doesn't have a type representing just a time without date either, so possible alternatives would be:

*Slightly hacky*: index another Date field with year/month/day 'clipped' to the same value, and the hour/min/sec taken from the existing fields (so all dates collapse to a single day), then a single range can match the hours on that day.

*Alternative*: index another field with the time represented as a string, and construct regex matches for the various conditions (eg between 2-4am inclusive: /^{02,03,04}/).

For either solution you can index the field and the queries should make efficient use of indexes, I believe. The 2nd solution seems slightly more sensible.

Comment: what would you suggest?